PrimeNg p-table paginator rowsPerPageOptions change issue
I use PrimeNg 15.2.0 version. I have rowsPerPageOptions change problem. I have a p-table which is empty in the beginning when page is loaded and it has paginator with dropdown options. After setting filter and clicking import data button, it is gotten data for the table. Now I can choose any given data from paginator dropdown options and it will present me that amount of data rows depending on my choice in paginator dropdown.
When data is imported and I change paginator dropdown value it works properly, but if I choose the value from paginator dropdown before data imported and then I import the data, my choice from paginator dropdown is not applied to data in the table. In previous versions of PrimeNg it worked, now it does not work.
There is a n event (onPage)="paginate($event)" which should help to handle the changes made in paginator dropdown, but it does not work (event is not called) in the beginning when there is no data on the table. When there is data it is possible to use (onPage).

You are not using PrimeFaces.
